# Caption in report builder is always truncated

Tags: delphi, reportbuilder

I am using report builder for printing some reports in my delphi code. I am setting a footer for all my reports. But when i have some text like "**Agency and Advertiser agree and acknowledge that Station's Advertising Terms and Conditions**" it is always truncated like "**Agency and Advertiser agree and acknowledge that Station's Advertising Terms and**".

My properties of the footer are

```
      object lblStatementFooter: TppLabel
        UserName = 'lblStatementFooter'
        HyperlinkColor = clBlue
        Border.BorderPositions = []
        Border.Color = clBlack
        Border.Style = psSolid
        Border.Visible = False
        Ellipsis = False
        Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
        Font.Color = clBlack
        Font.Name = 'Arial'
        Font.Size = 8
        Font.Style = []
        TextAlignment = taCentered
        Transparent = True
        WordWrap = True
        mmHeight = 3979
        mmLeft = 0
        mmTop = 794
        mmWidth = 203200
        BandType = 8
```

is it something i am missing here? Please help me out

Comment: Set Autosize = True on the label

Comment: In the designer view AutoSize is enabled and still the result is same

Comment: You can also use the TppMemo

Comment: @Ravaut123: I also tried with TppMemo but how to adjust its height dynamically so that my contents fit in it. I set the property Stretch to true but it doesnt help

Comment: If your using a `TppMemo` set the `Stretch` property to true, this stretches the memo field vertically to fit the text it contains, if your using a `TppLabel` setting`AutoSize = False` and `WordWrap = True` then increasing the height of the control will give the same effect (but not as dynamically)

Comment: I tried doubling the height of the text after setting the caption and it works but dont know whether this is a correct approach

Answer (score 1):

Because the footer is PrintHeight = phStatic.
You can't change the property to phDynamic.

What you can to is to program code in the FooterBeforePrint like

```
procedure FooterBeforePrint
begin
    if Memo1.Lines.Count >0 then
    begin    
      Footer.Height:= 0.4 * Memo1.Lines.Count;
      Memo1.Height:= Footer.Height;
    end;
end
```

Comment: I dont understand what is footer and what is the magic number 0.4 all about

Comment: Footer is the name of my footer. The code is write in the calc tab of the report builder IDE. 0.4 is just a number that I used for this example. The reale thing is that you must calculate the height of the footer and the memo because the footer.printheight property is only phStatic.